# Hibernate sending alien queries to database

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a web application backed by hibernate. For last few days, I have started closely monitoring mysql and found that hibernate is sending unknown queries to the database which infact are not being sent from any part of app.

query looks like

| /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='l |

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588435/hibernate-sending-superfluous-queries-to-the-database does this help?>

Comment: No. I am already using jboss internal pooling

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Hibernate or to the pooling mechanism. This is performed by the driver itself once a connection is made. The driver does that to configure itself. See the code in `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables()`

Comment: Thanks but how to avoid this. It has become issue now.

Comment: Well, this could be answered by looking at the documentation. But here it is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html > "Performance Extensions" > "cacheServerConfiguration". In other words, set the property "cacheServerConfiguration" to true in the JDBC URL.

Comment: Already having useConfig=maxPerformance. Still done the changes in connecting URL. Lets see how it behaves over the time. Will update .